# Bootstrap 3 Forms - Inline fields with Horizontal form

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've gone through a bunch of examples and I can't seem to find a clear answer on the right way to do this. I think my problem is compounded by having input-groups...

What is the correct way to code inline fields within a horizontal form? e.g.

```
Name:    [name        ]
Address: [address     ]
Radio:   o one  o two  o three
Dates:   [from |a] to [to  |b]
```

The docs seem to say to surround the inline fields in a class=form-inline but in the case of field groups, it doesn't seem to work...

The radio button formatting gets messed up a bit. But the date fields always wrap.

I can think of several ways to hack it into working. But I'd really like to know the "correct" way to fix it.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/pcarroll/2uDYz/4/

Anybody?

Answer (score 1):

For the radio buttons, you can modify `<div class="radio">` to `<div class="radio radio-inline">`

For the other elements you use variations of col-xs

http://jsfiddle.net/2uDYz/6/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to wrap the radio elements like that. Remove the div wrap and apply .radioinline or .checkbox-inline to the label. This is the proper way to do it.

http://jsfiddle.net/2uDYz/9/

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-3" for="type">Offer type</label>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input name="type" type="radio" value="One"> One
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input name="type" type="radio" value="One"> Two
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

For the date inputs, since you are using input-group, I would control them with col wraps.

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-xs-3" for="fromdate">Available from</label>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input class="form-control datepicker" name="fromdate" type="text" value="2014-01-01">
                        <div class="input-group-addon"> X </div>
                    </div>                  
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input class="form-control datepicker" name="todate" type="text" value="2014-01-01">
                        <div class="input-group-addon"> Y </div>
                    </div>                  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```